# Mechanism to programmatically connect to Azure SQL DB from the internet

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

I’m new to Azure and need some help with the architecture of what I’m trying to do before I start considering coding it up.

To mention up front, everything has been written in Powershell.  I’m happy to try and wrap my head around ASP.NET, C# or similar, but those aren’t something I’m too familiar with.

I have written some software and now need to create a licensing mechanism.  I have an Azure SQL DB that will hold customer details about their license details (customer company name, purchased date, expiry date, number of licenses, etc).  A service installed on the customer server  needs to connect to the DB, retrieve its record, then depending on what comes back, depends on whether it keeps running, in a nutshell.

I have read that one shouldn’t make the SQL DB internet facing for security reasons, so that means I need something resembling an old school web service.

The documentation out there is huge and confusing so far and being so new to Azure, I don’t really know which avenue to pursue to achieve what I’m aiming at.

I’m not assuming customers in the tens of thousands (but one can hope!), so I’m thinking one master table for admin purposes to keep tract of everything and a table per customer, with the table named the same as their customer ID.

What would be the best way to create something that I can connect to via Powershell that will forward the connection to the DB and allow the customer to query the table associated with their ID please?

So far, I’ve been through a LOT of documentation, read articles and looked at forums, but haven’t found any examples of what I’m trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:  I ended up writing a C# web app in Azure that forwards the request to the SQL back end based upon the username of the client connecting.
Thanks for the responses!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can set network based access controls on your sql server to allow access from specific IP addresses or Azure Virtual networks.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/network-access-controls-overview?view=azuresql

Comment: I suppose adding a customer’s IP address is one way, but it’s not the ideal solution.  Thanks for the suggestion!  $PossibleSolutions++
:)